# How to get/read Email ID from a from response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created an application where I am collecting form responses from various users. I am getting responses with email `id` in responses spreadsheet. As I don't want to store data in spreadsheet so I am reading data trough responses. I am facing some challenges please guide.

### Query 1

while using `onFormSubmit(e)` I am not able to read submitted form, given code is returning null:

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
Logger.log('usename:' + form.getId());
```

error " Cannot call method "getId" of null." although if I hard coded value of formid `var form =  FormApp.openById('<<form_id_xyz>>');` then it is working fine and I can read responses as well.
How can I get form responses for multiple users?

### Query 2

`getRespondentEmail();` is not working in my case. Even I use form id <<form_id_xyz>> and trying to get email id from responses which I have captured at the time of form submission `form.setCollectEmail(true);` I tried following code in `onFormSubmit(e)` function but dint get a result:

```
var formResponse=form.response;
Logger.log('email id of user: ' +  formResponses.getRespondentEmail());
```

and another way:

```
Logger.log('email id of user: ' +  form.getRespondentEmail());
```

and

```
Logger.log('email id of user: ' +  e.values[1]);
```

nothing works for me. Kindly guide.

Comment: if your apps script is created in the form itself, 

then only FormApp.getActiveForm(); will give you form. 

Whereas if you are apps script is in drive then FormApp.getActiveForm(); will return null.
Check this for your first query. Can you post your code for your second query.

Comment: ohk, my bad, I am creating forms dynamically from spreadsheet, so how can I capture form ID of submitted forms?

Comment: Relevent code to capture email id:

function onFormSubmit(e) {
           var form =  FormApp.openById('1ZQkN76JbZEpnWG9D0GQZfSWD8YHlP5nbuqIcfJpC9a0');  
           
//Reading responses    
   Logger.log('email : ' +   form.getRespondentEmail());
          Logger.log('email : ' +  formResponses.getRespondentEmail());  
          Logger.log('email : ' +  e.values[0]);  
         
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query 1: Hope it's clear in my comment.

Query 2:

Sorry to say, I don't understand your second query problem completely.

However as per your requirement I am suggesting this code.

If you have created a form you should know the form id (I assume) so try this code.

```
var form=FormApp.openById('your form id here'); 
//this returns your form which you created//

var responses=form.getResponses();
/// this will give you all responses of your form as an array////

///iterate the array to get respondent email id///

for(var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++){
   Logger.log(responses[i].getRespondentEmail());
}
```

Comment: Got it, the problem was here while reading responses. @formResponses.getRespondentEmail(). Thanks for the solution. Now It's working fine.

Comment: Hi Bharathi, I am clear with your comment for query 1, I have a single code in spreadsheet to generate dynamic forms for multiple users, but I am not able to trace the formID, could you please guide me further,  how can I get formId in onFormSubmit()?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to note that at the present time the answer to your question is: ***You can get what they enter, but you cannot get their true verified Email Address***. This is explained better [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882887/email-verification-using-google-app-script-and-google-forms) and one of the answers details some workarounds such as publishing form as a web script.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150226/how-to-get-read-email-id-from-a-from-response/23151745#23151745) displays what email address the user has *typed* into the form. There is no authentication to this beyond it having an @ symbol thus a user could type `foofoo@zoomZoom.com` and it would be viewed in the forms results and scripts.

What's annoying is that google IS capturing the user's true email address because if settings are set to `Allow One Response Per User`, then the user is limited to one submission -- regardless of what they put as their email account. I'm not sure why Google won't provide a method to view the submitter's login email address since it has been disclosed to the user that this will be disclosed.

Microsoft Forms does capture this.