# Email verification using google app script and google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form app which has, among others, an email id field.I want to verify that the email entered by user is the email which belongs to him. Pls note: I  DO NOT WANT TO VERIFY THE DOMAIN/SYNTAX OF EMAIL. All emails would be gmail ids, so if that helps, is there a way to send a mail validation link to their gmail accounts and on clicking the link, the entry is made to spreadsheet. Else its cancelled. 
Also the link must be valid for limited time only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can publish a Google script as a web app and add the email address of the recipient as a query parameter to this app. When the user clicks the link, the app is called, the email is verified and the app itself can log an entry into the spreadsheet.

Comment: Finally the answer from the man himself!! I learnt google script inspired by your wonderful blog http://ctrlq.org/code/19491-embed-twitter-rss. Thank you very much. I just wish to ask that is there a way I can verify one's twitter handle using app script? If you want, I can ask it as another question on SO. For now, I am accepting with upvote.

Comment: You can use UrlFetch to fetch the web page associated with the Twitter handle. If it doesn't return a 404, the handle is probably valid.

Comment: By "verify" I mean that the handle belongs to the person filling the form just as the gmail id. And regarding UrlFetch, are you sure that it will fetch data from URL not belonging to the domain where script is running? I guess we need jsonp for working with URLs outside of domain with javascript.